# Is this a jQuery Deferred API bug?

Tags: jquery, jquery-deferred

As the jQuery documentation say in  [deferred.notify()](http://api.jquery.com/deferred.notify/):

Any calls to .notify() after a Deferred is resolved or rejected (or any progressCallbacks added after that) are ignored.

But when i read jQuery source code, the progressCallback is just locked when the deferred object is resolved or rejected. So if the .notify() was not called before we call .resolve() or .reject(), the progressCallback will be disabled, but if the .notify() was called before we call .resolve() or .reject(), the progressCallback was just locked, and .progress() method is still available.

This issue exist in 1.8-edge version of jQuery.

You can check out the code example here:

````

```
var t = $('#test');
var de = $.Deferred();
de.progress(function(){t.append('progress 1<br/>');});
de.notify();
de.resolve();
de.progress(function(){t.append('progress 2<br/>');}); // should not be executed
de.progress(function(){t.append('progress 3<br/>');});
de.progress(function(){t.append('progress 4<br/>');});
de.progress(function(){t.append('progress 5<br/>');});
```

````

Comment: Do you see this part of that [same jQuery doc](http://api.jquery.com/deferred.notify/): `with the exception that any progressCallbacks added after the Deferred enters the resolved or rejected state are executed immediately when they are added,`?  So, the ones you add at the end should all be called once immediately.

Comment: @jfriend00 yes, you are right. I was wondering why would jQuery do that?

Comment: I guess it's because progress is meant to be active until the promise is fulfilled so once it is fulfilled, there's no future progress events.  Don't ask me to defend it - that's just the way it is.

Answer (score 0):

This is working as intended, although the documentation isn't crystal clear on the expected behaviour from that page. If you check the [`deferred.progress()` page](http://api.jquery.com/deferred.progress/) though, it says:

> When the Deferred is resolved or rejected, progress callbacks will no longer be called, with the exception that any progressCallbacks added after the Deferred enters the resolved or rejected state are executed immediately when they are added, using the arguments that were passed to the .notify() or notifyWith() call.